# Cloud Function deploy gen2 - function already exist error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

As I used to do in gen1, I first create a new function named `func_name` on **the web UI**, with a `Function entry name`.

Then on the CLI (Terminal) :

```
sudo gcloud functions deploy func_name --runtime=python39  --region=us-central1 --trigger-http
```

I keep getting the same error that :

```
Failed to create function, function already exists under 2nd gen environment
```

Of course it exist, I created it first via web so I can deploy it (?)

**EDIT**:
Removing the Function from the web UI, then deploy it **first time** from cli will create a `gen1` Function not 2. To create `gen2` function we need to add the flag `--gen2`, which amazingly produce error "unrecognized argument gen2" if you add it (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy)

It seems to me that `gen2` is some sort of beta version with so many unclear problems that I spend hours to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the gen2 error "unrecognized argument gen2", try to update your gcloud:
`gcloud components update`.
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem and solved by specifying the `beta` subcommand, so removing the Function from the web UI, then deploying it from the cli with

```
sudo gcloud beta functions deploy func_name --runtime=python39  --region=us-central1 --trigger-http --gen2
```

should work for you too