# Cloud Function can't deploy with argument --gen2?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I was trying everything possible, but the CLI (Terminal Mac) will not accept the argument --gen2 to create a generation2 Function.

```
sudo gcloud functions deploy func_name --gen2  --runtime=python39  --region=us-central1 --trigger-http
```

According to the docs : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy this need to be added. (also not clear why they write `[--gen2]` inside `[]` and on different docs they write `--gen2` (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-gcloud#functions-deploy-command-python)

Emitting this will create a `gen1` `Function`, but if you create the `gen2` Function on the **web** platform **first**, then you will not be able to *redeploy* it from cli ( because it see it as a duplicate and ask to delete the Function that is already exist).
I am so surprised by the unclarity and bugs by such a large company's new product.

Bottom line - I can't create gen 2 Function no matter what direction I choose.

Comment: Seems like you asked this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761656/cloud-function-deploy-gen2-function-already-exist-error please just keep one question an edit as necessary

Comment: Square brackets in a command synopsis mean the command flag, argument, etc. is **optional**.

Comment: Do not use **sudo** with standard commands.

Comment: Is your CLI up to date?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you got it thanks. i just updated it and got the same error, BUT now i can add --gen2 which will deploy it. But I wonder what is the logic behind asking devs to put all of these flags every time they deploy ? this should be a merge operation - so if i didn't mention the flags it will keep the current configuration.

Comment: Try this `gcloud config set functions/gen2 true`. Then, by default the deployment will be always in gen2 version.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update gcloud by running: `gcloud components update`